# Java first time create an Object will slowly than next create this Object

Tags: jvm, jvm-hotspot

I have a question about create an java object,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++){
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RestTemplate httpClient = new RestTemplate();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - now);
    }
}
```

this result is

```
1084
16
7
12
5
```

Obviously, the first time had spent 1084ms, but second only spend 16ms.
Why this happened in Java?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Code is lazy loaded and classes lazily initialised. The more code which has to be loaded and classes initialised the longer it takes.

If this is a concern you can do a dummy execution of the code so the first time you use it it will be faster.

Note: at this point almost none of the code has been compiled and it can be much, much faster after it has been called enough times to be compiled.

In terms of micro-benchmarks, I would ignore the first 2-10 seconds, and the first 20,000 calls which ever takes longer.

Comment: I have communicated by `javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();` in a web application, my log record this Object created spend time, first time it almost spent 3 seconds, if  I continuous called, this Object created very fast, but when I called after a minute, this Object spent 3 seconds to created again. Why a minute later, this spent time like first spent time? Thank you very very much!

Comment: @vincentren I wouldn't expect you need to create more than one of these clients as you should be able to reuse them. I suspect you are triggering a GC or you are running out of resources temporarily.

Comment: How can I reuse them? When I used this Object at static, I should call method of close, then next request I used this Object, it happed an exception that I closed this Object.  If GC cleaned, is this object should load again?

Comment: @vincentren If you want a to re-use an object you can't close it. If it has been GC-ed it's because you don't have a reference to it so you can't reuse it.  I wouldn't make it `static` unless there is no other way of sharing this resource. You might have one of these per thread which needs it and close it when the thread will no longer need it. Or you could share one between threads with synchronization, or use a resource pool. It depends on how you intend to use this connection.